# Throw Exception display error message in development but not in prod

Tags: php, exception

On my PHP app, when I try to throw an Exception, this one does'nt display in prod,
only in my localhost website.
I don't have any access to the log in production.

That's my code when this specific field is empty :

```
    if(empty($this->_dataProtected['gender'])){
        throw new Exception("miss gender");
    }
```

and on the other side, in my index :

```
try{
    $...Controller->add...();
} catch (Exception $e){
    $_SESSION['post']= $_POST;
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = $e->getMessage();
    $db = new \App\Data\Database();
    $q = "INSERT INTO errors 
                    (id_user, message, date_error, email_support) 
                    VALUES
                           ('".$_SESSION['infosUser']['id_user'] ."','". $e->getMessage() ."', NOW(),'john@doe.com')";
    $db->query2($q)->execute();
    header('Location: ?page=...&action=...');
    exit();
}
header("Location: ?page=...");
exit();
```

Comment: it should depends on php.ini display_errors = on. But since you don't control the prod env, all you can is logging the exception... or just adding quickly a line like file_put_contents to a file location you could reach somehow.. or using a better approach system wise.. but that's a longer process

Comment: The concept of Throw Exception is to avoid showing errors on production.. but to try to redirect to some url with showing errors on your log file, anyway share your code and we will try to see what happened there.

Comment: @MohcinBN @"Diego De Vita" I shown my code

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't display" there are no commands to place anything on the screen in the exception handler?

Comment: @Riggs Folly : in the page of redirection I have : echo $_SESSION['error_message']

Comment: Are you sure you have a `session_start()` in all these scripts

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes ! Like I said, it works in localhost

Comment: So it is redirecting to the page that we cannot see that is echoing this message. PLease remember, we cannot read your mind and we are not looking over your shoulder. We only know about your code, what you show us!!

Comment: Try ini_set('display_errors', true); at the beginning of your script, and return to us is errors shown or not?

Comment: `I don't have any access to the log in production`...this is not a sustainable or feasible situation for you as a developer if you're being expected to debug errors in production. Request access to the logs. P.S. A production system should _not_ be trying to display an exception message directly on screen though, it should always be logged and replaced on-screen with something generic and more user-friendly which doesn't reveal any technical details